# Can I deploy SSIS package (vs2012) to SQL server 2014?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a SSIS project built in VS2012, it was working well on SQL 2012 , now the SQL server is upgraded to 2014, Can I deploy it to SQL server 2014 directly ? Tried to upgrade the project in vs2015 but failed to execute script task on SQL server 2014.

Comment: Instead of trying to use an old tool, use the latest version of SSDT. It *is* free and supports all SQL Server versions. The latest version supports SSIS, SSAS, SSRS for all supported versions of SQL Server (ie 2008R2+)  and 2016

Comment: What *is* the error? Are you sure there isn't an actual problem with the script (eg referencing a non-existent column?), targeting the wrong runtime , or in fact, a missing runtime?

Answer (score 0):

SSis "versioning" is a nightmare! I suspect you'll need to convert packages from earlier versions into the newer version. You will need to ensure that the versions of SSDT-BI/Visual studio and Sql Server are compatible. It may also depend on whether you deploy to the ISC or not.

[MS Interoperability](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577(v=sql.120).aspx)